# Hibernate/JPA - object is an unsaved transient instance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Boa tarde pessoas!

Ao salvar um novo reajuste de contrato eu tenho que pesquisar outros contratos "semelhantes" ao que estou reajustando e reajustá-los também.

Para tal estava tentando utilizar um callback (`saveAfter`) após salvar o primeiro reajuste afim de reajustar os demais. O problema é que como o primeiro reajuste ainda não foi comitado quando eu tento salvar os demais ocorre o seguinte erro:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object is an unsaved transient
>   instance - save the transient instance before merging: [...]

Como eu faço para comitar todos registros de uma só vez? Abaixo segue a parte que interessa do código comentando o problema:

`ReajusteBO.java`:

```
    protected Reajuste saveOrUpdateAfter(Reajuste entity,
        Reajuste mergedEntity, Object... list) throws ApplicationException {

    if (entity.getReajustarVinculados().equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
        reajustarContratosVinculados(entity);

    return super.saveOrUpdateAfter(entity, mergedEntity, list);
}

public Integer reajustarContratosVinculados(Reajuste reajusteOrigem)
        throws ApplicationException {

        List<Contrato> contratos = contratoBO
                .findListByCriteria(Restrictions.eq("cliente", cliente));
        for (Contrato contrato : contratos) {
            if (contrato.getPlano().equals(
                    reajusteOrigem.getContrato().getPlano())) {

                Reajuste r = new Reajuste();
                r.setContrato(contrato);
                mergeEntity(r); // Nesta linha ocorre o erro
                num++;
            }
        }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: Olá! Qual o conteúdo do método `mergeEntity`? Como está o mapeamento das entidades `Reajuste` e `Contrato` ?

Comment: Basicamente é apenas o merge do JPA.
 public ENTITY_TYPE mergeEntity(ENTITY_TYPE entity){
  return getJpaTemplate().merge(entity);
 }

Answer (score 1):

Já resolvi. Este caso é um pouco específico, talvez a solução não sirva pros demais, mas o erro é que o `CallBack` para funcionar usa a entidade mesclada e eu estava modificando a entidade não mesclada.

Bastou eu passar para o método `reajustarContratosVinculados()` e a entidade mesclada que funcionou.

```
if (mergedEntity.getReajustarVinculados().equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
    reajustarContratosVinculados(mergedEntity);
```